# Показатели производительности и "здоровья " СУБД postgres

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите какие показатели производительности и здоровья БД стоит мониторить в postgresql?

Answer (score 4):

1. В первую очередь конечно нужно мониторить основные параметры ОС. Загрузка ЦПУ, Память, Своп, Диски. В случае с Линуксом помогут утилиты (top, htop, iostat, free)
2. Далее нужно смотреть какие запросы отнимают наибольшее количество процессорного времени, и конечно же стараться их оптимизировать. В этом помогут pg_stat_statements, powa (http://dalibo.github.io/powa/)
3. Далее очень важно мониторить статистику таблиц такие как index_scan, sequential_scan и локи (в идеале должно быть меньше seq_scan-ов). Эти данные можно снимать с таблиц pg_stat_user_tables, pg_locks.
4. Если используется connection polling то нужно следить за количеством соединений.

---

Ну и по хорошему нужно прикрутить мониторинг фреймворк для сборки и хранения статистики. Лично я использую sensu (http_s://sensuapp.org/
) уже с готовыми коммьюнити плагинами (http_s://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-postgres). Ну и конечно же powa.
В случае проблем можно конечно еще много что посмотреть, но вот это основные параметры и в основном их хватает.